# when select value from dropdwonlist i want to show it in for example div

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

I have a dropdownlist inside a form and a div. I want that, when i select a value from the dropdownlist, it shows in the div.

I've succeeded in this, but the problem is that the following selections ,after first one, are deleting previous results from the div.

```
public ActionResult SelectStudWhoWantReport(int StudentId = 0)
{
     IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.Students.Select(c => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)c.StudentID).Trim(),
                Text = c.StudentName
            });
     ViewBag.StudentId = items;
     Student WhomakeReport = db.Students.Find(StudentId);
     ViewBag.Name = WhomakeReport.StudentName;
     return View();
}
```

`viewbag` is the value that apear in `div`, When I select that how can I append the value of the `second select` with the `first select` to show the two in the div.

Comment: Not able to get your point, can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using a bad approach to solve your problem.

You are getting the result of the selection on your controller class, through a form submission I supose, and later send it to your View.

The problem is that when you call the controller your page is reloaded, thus you loose the previous info. There are different ways in which you'd be able to store previous results and build them on the View.

However, I think it's better that I explain you a more correct approach to solve this problem.

You should have a dropdownlist component on your View, which you load through your controller. I supose you already have this.

When the selection is made, instead of submitting the form, make an AJAX call to a method in the server which makes what you're currently doing in your controller (get the result depending on the selected id) and, instead of returning an ActionResult, just return the value you want.

When the AJAX callback returns, you'll have the result on your client code, so you just have to append it after previous results.

This approach not only is better from a MVC pattern point of view, it's also easier to implement and will allow your users to select elements in the dropdownlist and see the results without having to reload the whole page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer i will try this